# Design-time changes to user control property are not reachable by run-time code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

Basically I'm trying to create a user control that inherits `PictureBox`. One of the changes I want to make to the new picturebox is to add an `Opacity` property.

Everything seems to work fine except that when I change the Opacity value during design-time, that change doesn't affect the actual value of the property during run-time!

Here's my code:

```
Private _opacity As Integer
Public Property Opacity() As Integer
    Get
        Return _opacity
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _opacity = value
        If Image IsNot Nothing Then
            MyBase.Image = ChangeOpacity(_image, value)
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Private _image As Image
Public Shadows Property Image() As Image
    Get
        Return _image
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Image)
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = value

        If bmp IsNot Nothing Then
            _image = ChangeOpacity(bmp, Opacity)
        Else
            _image = bmp
        End If
        MyBase.Image = _image
    End Set
End Property
```

---

Well, I just used a different approach to *avoid* the problem. I overrode `OnPaint` method, moved the code of `ChangeOpacity` method to it, and removed the shadowed property: `Image` since I don't need it anymore. Now the problem is gone. **But** I'm still curious why the design-time changes to the `Opacity` property were not saved, and why it's saved now?!

Here's my new *working* code. It might help someone:

```
Public Class Pic
    Inherits PictureBox

    Private _opacity As Integer
    Public Property Opacity() As Integer
        Get
            Return _opacity
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _opacity = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(pe As PaintEventArgs)
        If Image IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim Gr As Graphics = pe.Graphics
            Dim colormatrix As New ColorMatrix
            colormatrix.Matrix33 = Opacity / 100
            Dim imgAttribute As New ImageAttributes
            imgAttribute.SetColorMatrix(colormatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.[Default], ColorAdjustType.Bitmap)
            Gr.DrawImage(Image, New Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height), 0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height,
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttribute)
        Else
            MyBase.OnPaint(pe)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with shadowing the Image-variable, I guess that the base-Image variable is called and used, could you check if the your Image-setter is called during runtime?

Comment: Could be your Opacity property was saving to the MyBase Image property, not your _Image value.  A PictureBox control is already double-buffered.  The Opacity range check you do in the constructor should happen in the Set block of the Opacity property.  Give _Opacity a default value of 10.

Comment: @Max Yes it's called and used but with the default `Opacity` value no matter what the design time value is!

Comment: @LarsTech `"Could be your Opacity property was saving to the MyBase Image property"` I don't get your point. The `Opacity` is a property of the control, what does it have to do with the `Image` property?

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN "Yes it's called and used but with the default Opacity value no matter what the design time value is! ". The variables get asigned their designtime-values in a single method defined by the designer. Maybe the designer initializes the Image variable first.

Comment: You are setting the image value in the Opacity.  The code you posted works (the Opacity value is saved in Design time on my machine).  It wasn't clear from your initial post if the Image property wasn't working correctly or if it is just the Opacity property.  If just the Opacity property, then remove the Image code and test that.

Comment: @Max This seems to be correct because in the constructor, the value is (0) but I tested it after that and I got the design-time value. Please put that in an answer.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, it looks like the design-time values get assigned after initializing the `Image` property as Max suggested. You both helped.. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Yes it's called and used but with the default Opacity value no matter what the design time value is!`.

The variables get assigned their designtime-values in a single method defined by the designer. The designer probably initializes the Image variable first.